# Python import files mac

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an exercise for a course in Python I have to complete. I have saved my methods/defs in one file and just need to figure out how to run it. I was hoping you could explain to me how to import files (I know the syntax"import filename"). When ever I do this I get an error. How do I change the file path of the import to the file on my desktop? I am using a mac and running IDLE 2.7.3

Comment: You can only import files that are in same folder with your app, or in subfolder with `__init__.py` file, or were installed for your Python's interpreter.

Answer (score 1):

If the files are in the same directory as that file you can just use

```
import <filename> #(without the <>)
```

However, if you are referring to the files in a separate directory use imp

```
import imp

module = imp.load_source('module.name', '/path/to/file.py')
module.SomeClass()
```

Comment: I get this error: Warning (from warnings module):
  File "/Users/Brandon/Documents/stuff/School/2012-2013/MITX/ProblemSet3/radiationExposure.py", line 24
    import math
RuntimeWarning: Parent module 'module' not found while handling absolute import

Comment: Do you have something literally named 'module'?  Because it seems like it's looking for something with that name.

Comment: askewchan is right. You need to replace the 'module' string with a string representing the name of the module you are loading.

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X, there are two basic ways to launch IDLE.  One is by double-clicking on an IDLE icon from the Applications folder in the Finder. (I'll call that `IDLE.app`)  The second is to launch IDLE from a terminal session shell with something like:

```
 idle2.7
```

I'll call that `bin/idle` because it refers to file in one of your system's `bin` directories.

When launching `bin/idle`, IDLE will inherit the current working directory of the shell and will add that directory to the front of the list of directories Python searches for imports.  You can examine that list of directories in the IDLE shell window:

```
 import sys
 sys.path
```

When you launch `IDLE.app`, however, it is not associated with any shell so there is no opportunity to tell IDLE which working directory to use.  In this case, `IDLE.app` uses your `Documents` folder/directory as its working directory: in shell notation, `~/Documents`, also spelled `/Users/your_login_name/Documents`.

You can manually manipulate `sys.path` in your Python program to add another directory for imports:

```
 import sys
 sys.path.insert(0, '/path/to/directory')
```

Another way to manipulate `sys.path` is to use the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable.  But, again, when using `IDLE.app`, there is no (easy) way to pass environment variables to it, unlike with `bin/idle`

So if you want to use `IDLE.app`, the simplest approach is to put into your `Documents` directory all of the files and packages directories that you want to be able to import.  Otherwise, use a terminal session, set the desired working directory and/or `PYTHONPATH` variable and launch `bin/idle`.  So something like:

```
cd ~/MyProject
export PYTHONPATH=~/"AnotherPackageDirectory"
idle2.7
```

Yet another approach is to install your modules in the default locations that Python searches and use Distutils or `easy_install` or `pip`.  But that's something to learn about later when you have a finished project.